# Any good UI evaluation documentation tools?

Tags: test-management, manual-testing, user-acceptance-testing, gui

I am looking for a specific tool which will help me document what I see when I perform web site usability evaluations. At the end of each evaluation, I need to create an report for my client. The ideal tool, if it exists, would contain at least the following 3 features:

- Multiple-choice answers: 
  I evaluate websites using several criteria and sub-items. For each criteria and item, I give grade/score, for example easy to use, moderately easy, complicated, very complicated to use. Each ranking or grade selection is explained.
- Upload-image feature: 
  As evidence/proof for having selected one grade/score over another, I would like to be able to upload a screenshot, after which an explanation would follow. I don't need the screenshot capture functionality as such, because I would use SnagIt. I just need the uploading feature.
- Free-text fields: 
  To be able to explain the reasoning behind the decision.

The final report would contain the criteria, a description of each criterium, the assigned grade/score, a description of what this grade means, one or more images (typically screenshots of a webpage or a part of one) and an explanation of certain elements shown in the screenshot. For this, I was thinking about mis-using an online survey service (SurveyMonkey or similar) or an e-learning assessment tool for this. It would be similar to an engine used to make those popular personality tests, in that you score many criteria and these scores -- and what they mean -- flows into an evaluation report.

The closest I've seen is Rapid Reporter which allows for its notes and screenshots function...but it doesn't allow for scoring an item using multiple choice along with a detailed description in a results reporting.

Does an animal like this exist? ;-)

Thanks a million,

Russell

Answer (score 3):

> I am looking for a specific tool which will help me document what I
>   see when I perform web site usability evaluations. At the end of each
>   evaluation, I need to create an report for my client.

As your demand above, I would think a tool called [qTrace](http://www.qasymphony.com/qtrace-overview.html) could help you out. It's a complete screen capture tool that helps a tester easily submits clear and accurate defect tickets, with features:

- captures both screenshots and user’s action;
- intelligently generates clear step-by-step narration of the test scenario;
- submits a ticket directly to a defect tracking system or generates a stand-alone document.

Comment: Welcome to SQA.SE, Nam! It's great when we can match up good tools with the people that need them. However, it's customary to make any affiliation public. Check out the policy in our faq: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a tool that helps with defects which is not what the question was about

Answer (score 2):

I would likely just use Word, using a template to contain my questions.

When I purchased a house earlier this year, the Inspector used Word. The resulting book looked exactly like what you are proposing for your final report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but TechSmith have a tool called Morae that is supposed to help with usability evaluations.

http://www.techsmith.com/morae.html

I've never used it myself so can't really tell you if it's what you are looking for. It does say on the feature list that it supports survey questions and capturing user actions.

And based on my experience with Jing and SnagIT it's coming from a good stable.

Worth a look I'd say. If you do get a chance to look at it I'd be interested to know if it works well for your usability test management.

Kind regards

Bill Echlin

http://www.TestManagement.com